# ModSecurity for URL Whitelisting

Tags: mod-security

I want to write a rule which can allow specific URL only. I have only two url's 
1: abc.com/configuration/
2: abc.com/update/

SecRule REQUEST_URI "!@beginsWith /configuration" \
"id:700003, phase:1,log,deny, msg:'Different URL Accessed'"

SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /update" \
"id:700004, phase:1,log,pass, msg:'Update URI accessed'"

How can I merge this two rule so one can override other?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to allow above URL's only rest I want that modsecurity will block.

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of things you could do here.

[By default a regex is used to match in ModSecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#rx) so you could write one rule to cover both URIs and block if not matched:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "!\/(configuration|update)\/" "phase:1,id:700003,block
```

You could do the same using [@pm](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#pm):

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "!@pm \/configuration\/ \/update\/" "phase:1,id:700003,block
```

Alternatively you could use [skipAfter](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#skipAfter), which would allow you to list URLs in different rules, and then have one blocking rule, which is skipped, if any of the preceding rules match:

```
SecMarker BEGIN_VALID_URL_CHECK
SecRule REQUEST_URI "!@beginsWith /configuration" \ "id:700003, phase:1,log,skipAfter:END_VALID_URL_CHECK,msg:'Different URL Accessed'"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /update" \ "id:700004, phase:1,log,skipAfter:END_VALID_URL_CHECK,msg:'Update URI accessed'"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "." \ "id:700005, phase:1,log,block,msg:'Another URI accessed - blocking'"
SecMarker END_VALID_URL_CHECK
```

Alternatively you could [allow](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#allow) the rules which match those patterns which stops processing this request in ModSecurity (this is probably a bad option as it will skip any other ModSecurity rules defined later in your config but I'm including it for completeness sake):

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "!@beginsWith /configuration" \ "id:700003, phase:1,log,allow,msg:'Different URL Accessed'"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /update" \ "id:700004, phase:1,log,allow, msg:'Update URI accessed'"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "." \ "id:700005, phase:1,log,block, msg:'Another URI accessed - blocking'"
```